# Basic forum on server with no interface?

Tags: wordpress, iphone, forum

I'm not really a server-side person – I generally do iPhone apps, though I've hacked together a few Wordpress sites.

I'm curious as to what web technologies people would use for the back-end of an iPhone app whose front end presents as a basic forum. In other words, people can create new threads, and respond to them - with plain text only.

The forum would not exist as a website.. the only way to access it would be on the phone.

What technology would people recommend I use? Ruby-on-Rails with Amazon S3 storage? Could I even use existing forum software and pass and receive data to and from it? Perhaps even a forum Wordpress plug-in? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mobile apps that provide access to forums, like [Forum Runner](http://www.forumrunner.net/) and [Tapatalk](http://www.tapatalk.com/). They seem to do this via a specific API. You can probably implement [this API](http://www.tapatalk.com/api/api.php) in your app, and then set up a [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) or other forum on your website to hold the actual data. You can then mask all access to the forum that does not use the API via the server configuration.